# Azure Stream Analytics: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I'm having a hard time tracking down a casting error in Azure Stream Analytics. The input data is coming from an Azure IoT Hub. Here's my query code:

```
-- Create average data from raw data
WITH 
AverageSensorData AS
(
    SELECT
        [Node],
        [SensorType],
        udf.round(AVG([Value]), 2) AS [Value],
        MAX(TRY_CAST([Timestamp] AS DateTime)) AS [Timestamp]
    FROM [SensorData]
    WHERE TRY_CAST([Timestamp] AS DateTime) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        [Node],
        [SensorType],
        TumblingWindow(minute, 2)
)

-- Insert average data into PowerBI-Output
SELECT 
    [Node],
    [SensorType]
    [Value],
    [Timestamp],
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        DATEPART(yy, [Timestamp]),
        DATEPART(mm, [Timestamp]),
        DATEPART(dd, [Timestamp]),
        0, 0, 0, 0) AS [Date]
INTO [SensorDataAveragePowerBI] 
FROM [AverageSensorData]
```

While this runs fine most of the time (at least for a couple of hundreds or thousands of input entities) it will eventually fail. After having turned on Diagnostic logs I was able to find the following eror message in the corresponding execution log (in reality it was in JSON format, I cleaned it up a little for readability):

> Message: Runtime exception occurred while processing events, - Specified cast is not valid. OutputSourceAlias: averagesensordata; Type: SqlRuntimeError, Correlation ID: 49938626-c1a3-4f19-b18d-ee2c5a5332f9

And here's some JSON input that probably caused the error:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2017-04-27T00:00:00.0000000",
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-04-27T07:53:52.3900000Z",
        "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-04-27T07:53:50.6877268Z",
        "IoTHub": {
            /* Some more data that is not being used */
        },
        "Node": "IoT_Lab",
        "PartitionId": 0,
        "SensorType": "temperature",
        "Timestamp": "2017-04-27T09:53:50.0000000",
        "Value": 21.06
    },
    {
        "Date": "2017-04-27T00:00:00.0000000",
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-04-27T07:53:53.6300000Z",
        "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-04-27T07:53:52.0157515Z",
        "IoTHub": {
            /* Some more data that is not being used */
        },
        "Node": "IT_Services",
        "PartitionId": 2,
        "SensorType": "temperature",
        "Timestamp": "2017-04-27T09:53:52.0000000",
        "Value": 27.0
    }
]
```

The first entry was the last one to go through, so the second one might have been the one breaking everything. I'm not sure, though, and do not see any suspicious values here. If I upload this as test data within the Azure portal then no errors are being raised.

The query above explicitely uses casting for the `[Timestamp]` column. But since I'm using [TRY_CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Mt643735.aspx) I wouldn't expect any casting errors:

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

As I said, the error only appears once in a while (sometimes after 20 minutes and sometimes after a couple of hours) and cannot be reproduced explicitely. Does anyone have an idea about where the error originates or if there is a chance of getting more detailed error information?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE:** Here's the source of the `udf.round` function:

```
function main(value, decimalPlaces) {
    if (typeof(value) === 'number'){
        var decimalMultiplier = 1;
        if (decimalPlaces){
            decimalMultiplier = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
        }
        return Math.round(value * decimalMultiplier) / decimalMultiplier
    }

    return value;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's been a while since I wrote this, so I'm not a hundred percent sure why I wrote exactly this code. One thing I do remember, though, is, that I all the analyzed messages always contained a valid number in the respective field. I still think that there's a good chance of this function being responsible for my problem.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this happens?

Comment: @juunas Unfortunately I haven't yet. This topic is on hold right now, but I will very probably have to get back to it sooner or later. I will provide a solution here, if and when I find one.

Comment: Can you post the source and configuration for your custom round() function? I've had this issue when a UDF doesn't return a value of the type that it's configuration would dictate.

Comment: @runemoennike Thanks for pointing in that direction, I can't really believe I missed this before. I updated my question.

Comment: One thing that pops out now, is that your round() function will return different variable types depending on the input. I.e. if given a number, it returns a number, but if given a string it returns a string. That will give exactly the error you mention if you have defined the return type in the function setup to be anything but "any". Similarly I think AVG() fails if given something that's not a number.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable, thanks for your effort. If I recall correctly, however, I only sent numeric values. But now that I think about it: There's always the chance some other app sent messages to the IOT hub. Unfortunately, I can't test this, because the project has been paused. I'll test this as soon as we get back to it.